# CMake: Can subdirectories inherit compile features?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++14

I have a C++ project that consists of a main program (`main.cpp`), a header that defines an abstract class (`algorithm.hpp`), and a subdirectory (`algorithms/`) full of classes that implement the abstract class.  I've configured CMake to build the subdirectory as an object library:

```
# algorithms/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(algorithms_lib OBJECT
  algo1.cpp
  algo2.cpp
  # etc.
)
```

In my project's root directory, I use this object library as one of the application's sources:

```
# Top-level CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(MyApp CXX)

add_subdirectory(algorithms)

add_executable(my-app
  main.cpp
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:algorithms_lib>
)
```

My application is written in C++14, so I need to tell CMake to use the correct compile options for that.  I don't want to require CMake version 3.8 (since it's not packaged in some recent Linux distros that I want to support), so I can't use the `cxx_std_14` compile feature; instead, I've listed a bunch of individual language features that I use:

```
# Top-level CMakeLists.txt (cont.)
target_compile_features(my-app PUBLIC
  cxx_auto_type
  cxx_constexpr
  cxx_defaulted_functions
  # ...14 more lines...
)
```

The problem is, these features only apply to the top-level `my-app` target, not the `algorithms_lib` target, so the sources in the subdirectory don't get compiled as C++14.

I know I could copy the whole big `target_compile_features` block into `algorithms/CMakeLists.txt`, but I'd rather not do that — especially since this example is simplified and I actually have *nine* such subdirectories, each building its own object library.  That'd be a lot of duplication of boilerplate code.

Is there a way to set compile features globally for all C++ targets in the project, including subdirectories?  Or would it be better to get rid of `add_subdirectory` and the object library, and just list all the individual subdirectory files in the top-level `add_executable` command?  I'm new to CMake, so I don't know what the "best practices" are for this sort of thing.

Comment: Sub `CMakeLists.txt` will _inherit_ all compiler setting from the main entry already.

Comment: Even for a target-specific property like `COMPILE_FEATURES`?  It doesn't seem to work that way — when I run `make VERBOSE=1`, I see `-std=gnu++14` on the line that compiles `main.cpp`, but not on the lines that compile the subdirectory files.  And the subdirectory files fail to compile, with errors like "'array' is not a member of 'std'", which means the compiler was using C++98.

Comment: I found that instead of a big `target_compile_features` list, I can do `set_property(TARGET my-app CXX_STANDARD 14)`, and that works in CMake versions going back to 3.1.  But `set_property(GLOBAL CXX_STANDARD 14)` has no effect — looks like it can only be set on individual targets, not inherited from global scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you want to put the following at the top of your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

These set defaults for the same-named target properties without the leading `CMAKE_`. The equivalent target properties do the following:

`CXX_STANDARD yy` sets the desired minimum C++ standard your code wants to use.

`CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED bb` says whether `CXX_STANDARD` is a requirement (`bb` is `YES` or some other boolean equivalent) or whether it is just desirable (`bb` is `NO` or equivalent).

`CXX_EXTENSIONS bb` enables (`bb = YES`) or disables (`bb = NO`) compiler extensions.

You don't need to specify individual compiler features to achieve what you're ultimately trying to do (enable C++14 for your targets). You can find a full discussion of this whole area [here](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/).

Comment: Aha — I was focusing on properties (since that's what `CXX_STANDARD` is) and didn't think about variables.  Thanks.  (And yeah, I know about `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` and `CXX_EXTENSIONS`; I left them out of my simplified example since they're tangential to the problem.)